# How to reduce spaces between grids for graph in chart.js

Tags: php, jquery, graph, chart.js

I have recently worked on showing some business analytics in graph, which works fine. Now I want to reduce extra spaces between the grids.

Is there any option or attribute for customize their grinding system?

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this one **After dataset**:

```
grid: {
            show: true,
            aboveData: true,
            color: "#3f3f3f",
            labelMargin: 10,
            axisMargin: 0,
            borderWidth: 0,
            borderColor: null,
            minBorderMargin: 5,
            clickable: true,
            hoverable: true,
            autoHighlight: true,
            mouseActiveRadius: 100
        }
```